# Что не так в моем коде, и как подтянуть навыки?

Tags: android, java

Отправил тестовое задание на позицию Android разработчика, но в ответ они написали:

> После ознакомления с тестовым заданием, мы отметили, что у вас недостаточный уровень знания принципов ООП и принципов построенийAndroid-приложений.
> Если вы подтянете свой уровень знаний, лучше изучите ООП и каким образом применять его принципы для построения приложений, то мы могли бы вернуться к вопросу рассмотрения вашей кандидатуры в будущем.

Я самоучка, учился по книгам, статьям и т.д. , можете опытным глазом посмотреть что в моем коде не так в плане ООП и принципов построения? И как апргрейдить эти навыки? 
Код на gitHub, т.к. классов не один и не два https://github.com/Vlad161/Products

Comment: Не вижу, где в таком тестовом задании надо юзать ООП =D
Разве что вместо Activity порекомендовал бы использовать фрагменты.

Comment: Функция fillLists() в MainActivity немного сбивает с толку. Лучше бы прям в ней вызывать Adapter, а не менять значения глобальных переменных. Придирка конечно, но она выбивается из концепции ООП =)
Upd.: Метод readJsonFromAsset() можно сделать статичным и вызывать без создания экземпляра класса. Ещё кое где не самые очевидные названия - is.available(), is.read(), is.close() сильно сбивают, такое ощущение, что это проверки ("this is available?"), но это уже к читабельности относится

Comment: посмотрел кратко.

 - неочевидное размещение файлов
 - `catch (JSONException e) { }`


То, что у Вас много классов, еще не говорит, что Вы умеете пользоваться ООП. И вообще, в java сложно написать что то без единого класса.

Comment: помоему, там все явно видно: вместо того, чтобы парсить поля из JSON объекта и передавать их по отдельности в активность, нужно создать класс Продукт, инициализировать его и работать с ним во всех активити

Comment: В коде очень много неправильной обработки исключений. Например, внутри `JSONReadFromAsset.readJsonFromAsset()` молча глотаются все исключения, в следствии чего метод может вернуть `null`, на вызывающей стороне же отсутствуют соответствующие проверки. Как результат — потенциальный `NullPointerException` в `MainActivity.fillLists()`. И таких моментов в коде немало. Ну и вообще, отлавливать исключения по базовому типу (`Exception`, `Throwable`) — плохая идея.

Comment: тоже посмотрел код, вполне читабельно, неплохой, но я не знаю, про что, по такому тестовому проекту, можно судить, здесь не видно применения чегото большего, чем 3 первых урока по андроиду - активити, переход между ними и все, а может это все что от тебя надо было компании =)

Comment: @Suvitruf @nilagor @KoVadim @Роман Захаров @falstaf @Gorets Спасибо большое за ответы, к слову опыт работы 3 месяца, хочется сменить компанию, как видите в этой компании ничему не научился. А можете дать ссылки на статьи или книги (желательно на русском) как апгрейдить эти навыки? Буду очень благодарен)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ работодателя очень похож на стандартную отписку, поэтому не стоит воспринимать его буквально. После просмотра вашего проекта (кстати, неплохо было бы написать, что именно от вас хотели, можно выдержку из тестового задания) остались такие замечания:

1. Имена классов. Обычно имена классов - существительные (`JSONReadFromAsset` стоило бы назвать `JSONAssetReader`). К тому же стоит придерживаться какого-то общего стиля именования (два класса-активити заканчиваются на `Activity`, третий почему-то нет).
2. Скорее всего от вас ждали минимальной реализации MVC. Стоило создать bean для хранения сведений о продукте и добавить уровень абстракции DAO для извлечения данных из файла. Как-то так:

---

```
public interface ProductDAO {
    List<Product> getProducts();
}

public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDAO {
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        // здесь вытаскиваем список продуктов из JSON
    }
}
```

---

Таким образом вы бы отделили реализацию получения данных от логики их обработки, получив возможность изменять способ получения данных, не затрагивая основную логику программы.

Насчёт "подтянуть навыки ООП" - читайте [Head First Design Patterns](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=1&pvalue=Head+First+Design+Patterns&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0) и [GOF](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201633612).

Comment: @fori1ton Спасибо большое за ответы, а есть что то на русском? Читать на англ. могу , но с частым подглядыванием в словарь

Comment: @Vlad161, конечно, обе книги переведены на русский, просто я не помнил их точного названия на русском и мне было лень искать. Вот, нашёл переводы: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2457392/, http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/20216992/

Comment: @fori1ton сейчас читаю Фримен Эр., Фримен Эл., Сьерра К., Бейтс Б. - Паттерны проектирования - 2011 , хорошая книга. Дочитаю, и буду читать по вашим рекомендациям, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Вполне нормально написано, действительно похоже на отписку. Я бы немного погундел на:

1. Постоянное использование литеральных констант, которые имеет смысл объявить как `final static String ID="id";` ну и т.д.
2. Злоупотребление анонимными классами обработчиков - ухудшает читаемость;
3. Не совсем единообразный стиль именования (naming convention);
4. Отсутствие бина `Product`, это бы существенно упростили бы код - например даже отсылка через `Intent` extras, ну не говоря о прочих вкусностях - наверное это самое серьезный недостаток вашего кода;
5. Отсутствие типизированных исключений;
6. Возможно имело бы смысл использовать стороннюю либу для парсинга Json массива (типа Google GSON) - ну типа показали бы что умеете работать со сторонними либами, а не каждый раз изобретаете велосипед.

А так вполне нормально. Для начинающего вполне тянет на "четверочку".

**Update**

Да, еще из существенного: вам надо "посадить" читалку Json массива в `IntentService` или в `Runnable` с извещением об окончании работы через Broadcast. А на отображение продукта поставить "ожидалку" ждущую кастомный приватный Broadcast от читателя Json массива. В противном случае, если придется читать Json из сети - у вас код будет нерабочий.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ Спасибо большое за ответ, к слову опыт работы 3 месяца, хочется сменить компанию, как видите в этой компании ничему не научился. А можете дать ссылки на статьи или книги (желательно на русском) как апгрейдить эти навыки? Буду очень благодарен)

Answer (score 2):

Суть претензии в отсутствии ООП вполне ясна: У Вас просто нету прикладной модели. Из Вашего кода невозможно выделить целостные объекты (продукт, список продуктов и т.д.) и их способы взаимодействия. Например, для данной задачи (как я её понимаю без самого описание задачи) я бы выделил следующие объекты:

```
Product //класс содержащий всю информацию о продукте и возможные действия над ним(ид, имя, продать, купить....)

ProductCollection //Класс содержащий набор продуктов и операции над этим набором (добавить, удалить, загрузить из адаптера

ProductAdapter //Базовый класс который предоставляет методы по получению продуктов из источников данных
```

И далее развивать эти классы, чтобы показать возможности инкапсуляции, наследования и прочих возможностей ООП. Например адаптер - сделать интерфейсом.

Comment: @Чад, с вашей мыслью согласен, но не совсем понятно назначение класса `ProductCollection`. Зачем делать отдельный класс, если можно сделать `List<Product>`?

Comment: @fori1ton, Это скорее привычка, полезность в расширяемости в дальнейшем. И, безусловно `ProductCollection extends List<Product>`. И, опять же вопрос переносимости кода. Если у Вас не будет класса List<?> и его придётся заменять другим, то прикладная логика бы не страдала.

Comment: @Чад, поясните, пожалуйста, фразу

> Если у Вас не будет класса `List<?>` и его придётся заменять другим

Класс `List<?>` как бы есть везде, где есть Java (параметризованный - с версии 1.5, непараметризованный - с 1.2), это класс из стандартной библиотеки. Если `List` для вас слишком конкретно, то можно использовать `Collection`.

Comment: А если мы портируем не на java? На другой ООП например? И у нас уже достаточно много прикладного кода, который оперирует только прикладной моделью.

Comment: Добавление абстракций для возможности портирования приложения на другой язык - это, на мой взгляд, overengineering. Особенно для тестового задания.

Comment: Подобный подход, имхо, полностью оправдает себя, как только к коллекции `Product`'ов понадобится добавить, например, метод извлечения продукта из коллекции по SKU, в дополнение к традиционному для `List`'а извлечению по индексу. Или, например, метод, подсчитывающий общую стоимость продуктов в коллекции. Или что-то иное. Вариантов может быть множество. В случае с `ProductCollection` это решается тривиально и легко. В случае же с повсеместным использованием в коде `List<Product>` — уже не так просто.

Comment: @fori1ton, я же написал что это для дальнейшего. И в случае с тестовой задачей, овер инженеринг приветствуется обычно. Ну и ещё аргумент - это более жёсткое выделение уровня прикладной модели.
@falstaf, с языка сняли :-)

Comment: @Чад @fori1ton @falstaf Спасибо большое за ответы, к слову опыт работы 3 месяца, хочется сменить компанию, как видите в этой компании ничему не научился. А можете дать ссылки на статьи или книги (желательно на русском) как апгрейдить эти навыки? Буду очень благодарен)